# use HDF5 dll in Delphi application

Tags: c, delphi, dll, hdf5

I would like to work with HDF5 (https://www.hdfgroup.org/) in my Delphi 10.2 Windows 10 64bit application.

I use the hdf5.dll (which is written in C) with the following declarations:

```pascal
const
  H5P_DEFAULT: Integer = 0;

  H5F_ACC_RDONLY: Integer = $0000;  //*absence of rdwr => rd-only */
  H5F_ACC_RDWR: Integer = $0001;    //*open for read and write    */
  H5F_ACC_TRUNC: Integer = $0002;   //*overwrite existing files   */
  H5F_ACC_EXCL: Integer = $0004;    //*fail if file already exists*/
  H5F_ACC_DEBUG: Integer = $0008;   //*print debug info      */
  H5F_ACC_CREAT: Integer = $0010;   //*create non-existing files  */

type
  hid_t = Integer;
  hsize_t = UINT64;
  hssize_t = INT64;
  size_t = Cardinal;
  herr_t = Integer;
  unsigned = Cardinal;

  H5_ih_info_t = record
   index_size: hsize_t;
   heap_size: hsize_t;
  end;

  Tsohm =record
    hdr_size: hsize_t;
    msgs_info: H5_ih_info_t;
  end;

  TH5F_info_t = record
    super_ext_size: hsize_t;
    sohm: Tsohm;
  end;
  PH5F_info_t= ^TH5F_info_t;

//initializes the HDF5 library
function H5open: herr_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//flushes all data to disk, closes all open HDF5 objects, and cleans up all memory used by the HDF5 library
function H5close: herr_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//retrieves the major, minor, and release numbers of the version of the HDF5 library
function H5get_libversion( var majnum: unsigned; var minnum: unsigned; var relnum:unsigned): herr_t;  cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

// Opens an existing HDF5 file.
function H5Fopen(filename: PAnsiChar; flags: unsigned; fapl_id: hid_t): hid_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//Terminates access to an HDF5 file.
function H5Fclose(file_id: hid_t): herr_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//Returns global information for a file
function H5Fget_info2(obj_id: hid_t; file_info: PH5F_info_t): herr_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//Creates a new simple dataspace and opens it for access.
function H5Screate_simple(rank: Integer; current_dims: Pointer; maximum_dims: Pointer): hid_t; cdecl; external 'hdf5.dll';

//Creates a new group and links it into the file.
function H5Gcreate2(loc_id: hid_t; aname: PAnsiChar;  lcpl_id: hid_t; gcpl_id: hid_t; gapl_id: hid_t): hid_t; cdecl;  external 'hdf5.dll';
```

The following code

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  status: herr_t;
  majnum, minnum, relnum: unsigned;
  file_id: hid_t;
  group_id: hid_t;
  dataspace_id: hid_t;
  dataset_id: hid_t;
  dims: array[0..1] of hsize_t;
  file_info: TH5F_info_t;
  pfile_info: PH5F_info_t;
begin
  status := H5open;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5open ' + IntToStr(status)); //status=0 -> OK

  status := H5get_libversion(majnum, minnum, relnum);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5get_libversion ' + IntToStr(status)); //status=0 -> OK
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(majnum)); //majnum=1
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(minnum)); //minnum=10
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(relnum)); //relnum=6
                                     //-> version 1.10.6.

  file_id := H5Fopen('example.h5', H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5Fopen ' + IntToStr(file_id));  //file_id=0 ->

  pfile_info:=@file_info;
  status:=H5Fget_info2(0, pfile_info);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5Fget_info2 ' + IntToStr(status)); //status=-1 -> ERROR

  group_id:=H5Gcreate2(file_id, 'testgroup', H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5Gcreate2 ' + IntToStr(group_id)); //group_id=-1 -> ERROR

  dims[0]:=4;
  dims[1]:=6;

  dataspace_id := H5Screate_simple(2, @dims, nil);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5Screate_simple ' + IntToStr(dataspace_id)); //dataspace_id=2 -> OK

  status:=H5Fclose(file_id);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5Fclose ' + IntToStr(status)); //status=-1 -> ERROR

  status:=H5close;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('H5close ' + IntToStr(status)); //status=0 -> OK
end;
```

gives this output

```
H5open 0
H5get_libversion 0
1
10
6
H5Fopen 0
H5Fget_info2 -1
H5Gcreate2 -1
H5Screate_simple 2
H5Fclose -1
H5close 0
```

H5Fopen seems to work but all functions which uses the file_id afterwards return -1 meaning that an error occurred.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Without seeing more code we can't know what's wrong. We can't see any type declarations for instance. Make a minimal C example that does this. Then make the same code in Delphi. Then find the first function call that differs. Then dig deeper

Comment: I added the type declarations.

Comment: Unfortunately I have almost no knowledge of C and not much experience in using external DLLs in Delphi. So I don't really have a plan how to debug this. I would be nice if you could give me some more hints how I should proceed.

Comment: My advice would be to learn enough C to write a simple program calling the DLL, and enough to be able to translate the header file accurately. It never ceases to amaze me that people expect to succeed at tasks like this without spending the time learning the required skills. That's what I did when I first needed to do tasks like this.

Comment: Your declaration for H5FGetInfo2 is wrong. In the C declaration, file_info is a pointer to a H5F_info2_t. Please go here: https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/H5F_GET_INFO2 to view the declaration for H5F_info2_t. You may have other incorrect declarations, so please check those, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Dave Nottage is the answer. The types have been incorrect.